# Haskell: Specifying equal-length constraints of lists in the type system

Tags: list, haskell, type-systems, dependent-type

In Haskell, I often have a function like `f`, which accepts a list and returns a list of equal length:

```
f :: [a] -> [a]  -- length f(xs) == length xs
```

Similarly, I might have a function like `g`, which accepts two lists that should be of equal length:

```
g :: [a] -> [a] -> ...
```

If `f` and `g` are typed as above, then run-time errors may result if their length-related constraints are not satisfied. I would therefore like to encode these constraints in the type system. How might I do this?

Please note that I'm looking for a practical framework that may be used in everyday situations, adding as little intuitive overhead to the code as possible. I am particularly interested to know how you would deal with `f` and `g` yourself; that is, would you attempt to add the length-related constraints to their types, as asked here, or would you leave them with the types as given above for simplicity of code?

Comment: Are you OK with adding another tool to the toolbox? Liquid Haskell can encode such a property easily, but the GHC Haskell type system would require a new type, such as a GADT with Peano numbers.

Comment: Using a length-indexed list type also makes your functions incompatible with functions that work on ordinary lists, and you lose (or have to reimplement) GHC's list fusion.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the suggestion of Liquid Haskell (also mentioned in Justin's answer). Providing it is mature (i.e., not experimental), and does not adversely affect the performance of the compiled code, I would not be against adding toolkits to solve the answer. Reid, thanks for your observation; loosing compatibility with existing functions/list-fusion is something that I'm keen to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code is adapted from [Gabriel Gonzalez's blog](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/gadts.html) in combination with some information supplied in the comments:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- A List of length 'n' holding values of type 'a'
data List n a where
    Nil  :: List Z a
    Cons :: a -> List m a -> List (S m) a

-- Just for visualization (a better instance would work with read)
instance Show a => Show (List n a) where
    show Nil = "Nil"
    show (Cons x xs) = show x ++ "-" ++ show xs

g :: (a -> b -> c) -> List n a -> List n b -> List n c
g f (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons (f x y) $ g f xs ys
g f Nil Nil = Nil

l1 = Cons 1 ( Cons 2 ( Nil ) ) :: List (S (S Z)) Int
l2 = Cons 3 ( Cons 4 ( Nil ) ) :: List (S (S Z)) Int
l3 = Cons 5 (Nil) :: List (S Z) Int

main :: IO ()
main = print $ g (+) l1 l2
       -- This causes GHC to throw an error:
       -- print $ g (+) l1 l3
```

This alternative list definition (using GADTs and DataKinds) encodes the length of a list in its type. If you then define your function `g :: List n a -> List n a -> ...` the type system will complain if the lists are not of the same length.

In case this would (understandably) be too much extra complication for you, I'm not sure using the type system would be the way to go. The easiest is to define `g` using a monad/applicative (e.g. `Maybe` or `Either`), let `g` add elements to your list depending on both inputs, and sequence the result. I.e.

```
g :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> Maybe [c]
g f l1 l2 = sequence $ g' f l1 l2
  where g' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (Just $ f x y) : g' f xs ys
        g' f [] [] = []
        g' f _ _ = [Nothing]

main :: IO ()
main = do print $ g (+) [1,2] [2,3,4] -- Nothing
          print $ g (+) [1,2,3] [2,3,4] -- Just [3,5,7]
```

Comment: Note that this definition isn't really too usable in real code, because it forbids Functor, Appilcative, Traversable, Foldable, Monad, etc. instances, which end to be the most effective ways to work with types like these because they all offer length-preserving or length-agnostic operations.  Also, in modern haskell, using `DataKinds` to create a Nat *kind* is preferred too because it prevents some meaningless `List` type instantiations.

Comment: Many thanks, Sam. This, as well as Justin's answer, looks like what I want (although it will take me a while to fully understand your answer). Presently, I think I prefer Justin's as his types for `f` and `g` feel more intuitive to me. I wonder if I could ask you the same as I asked Justin; that is, if you were to implement `f` and `g`, would you annotate them as in your code snippet (and thanks, by the way, for the MWE), or would you leave them unannotated, with the types initially given in my question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the annotations, could you explain?

Comment: To clarify Justin L.'s comment a bit, you can improve your type by changing the order of its arguments from `List a n` to `List n a`.

Comment: I meant, if you were to need to implement the functions `f` and `g`, would you bother trying to specify their length-related constraints in the type system? In the past, I have always just defined `f` with the type `[a] -> [a]` and added a comment in the code that its result shall be of equal length to its argument. Today, for whatever reason, I felt more inclined than normal to provide a guarantee that this would be the case (i.e., by means of the type system). How do you normally deal with the likes of `f` and `g`?

Comment: In modern GHC it's preferable to use `DataKinds` and `data Nat = Z | S Nat`. Also, as dfeuer pointed out, the type parameters should be flipped, so we can create the usual instances (and I should mention that `Eq`, `Ord`, `Foldable`, `Functor` and `Traversable` are all derivable with `StandaloneDeriving`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated the answer. @user196429: I think it's very situational whether you want the same-length guarantee on the type-level. It's really all about how important it is to you to get the error at compile-time. Personally I would probably go for the monadic (/applicative) failure option in most situations, because as Reid Barton and others mention it's quite a hassle to change the whole list type.

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden Thanks for your answer and comments. If I understand correctly, I'm unable to define `readList :: FilePath -> List n c`, which I perhaps should have realised a little earlier ("the length of the list must be known at *compile time*"!), and so it unfortunately it's not exactly what I want, but I'm getting the impression that I cannot do exactly what I want with present-day Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

The lack you observe is because the information of length is not a part of the *type* of the list; because the type checker is meant to reason about types, you can't specify invariants in your functions *unless* the invariants are in the *type* of the arguments themselves, or on typeclass constraints or type family-based equalities.  (There are some haskell pre-processors, though, like Liquid Haskell, that allow you to annotate functions with invariants like this that will be checked on compilation.)

there are many haskell libraries that offer list-like data structures with length encoded in the type.  Some notable ones are *linear* (with `V`) and *fixed-vector*.

The interface for `V` goes something like this:

```
f :: V n a -> V n a -> V n a
g :: V n a -> V n a -> [a]
-- or --
g :: V n a -> V n a -> V ?? a -- if ?? can be determined at compile-time
```

Note the particular pattern of our first type signature for `g`: We take two types where we care about the lengths, and return a type that *doesn't* care about the length, losing information.

In the second case, if we *do* care about the length of the result, the length has to be known at compile-time for this to make sense.

Note that `V` from linear actually doesn't wrap a list, but a Vector from the vectors library.  It also requires *lens* (the linear library, that is), which is admittedly a huge dependency to pull in if all you want is length-encoded vectors.  I think the vector type from *fixed-vectors* does use something more equivalent to a normal haskell list...but I'm not totally sure.  In any case, it has a `Foldable` instance, so you can convert it to a list.

Do remember of course that if you plan to encode lengths in your functions like this...Haskell/GHC has to be able to see that your implementation typechecks!  For most of these libraries, Haskell will be able to typecheck things like this (if you stick with things like zipping and fmapping, binding, ap-ping).  For most useful cases this is true...however, sometimes your implementation just can't be "proven" by the compiler, so you'll have to "prove" it to yourself in your head, and use some sort of unsafe coercion.

Comment: Many thanks, Justin, this looks like what I want, although I'll need a moment to understand your answer. In the mean time, I wonder if you could add a comment: if you were to implement `f` and `g`, is this how you choose to implement them yourself, or would you prefer to leave them "unannotated" (i.e., as typed in my original question)?

Comment: For anyone else, I believe that the `V` type in this answer refers to: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.1/docs/Linear-V.html

Comment: Sometimes you can also "prove" things that the compiler is not able to infer by adding some code so to build a suitable "proof". This more or less requires one to pretend Haskell is more like Agda (albeit with different types). This is not for the faint of heart, of course, but can avoid the unsafe coercion you mention at the end of the answer.

Comment: @user196429 There are a lot of situations where I've benefited greatly from having type safety in list lengths.  Typically these are situations where an entire *class* of buggy implementations/programs are completely eliminated.  The situation that you mentioned (you want to annotate that your function takes same-length lists) does happen, but what happens more for me is I write the annotation first and then attempt to implement it; GHC will then *guarantee* that my implementation is correct.  this eliminates scores of bad implementations off the bat, and I think this is often a great benefit.

Comment: @justinL Thanks for your answer and comments. I like the cleanness of the type-definitions of `f` and `g` in your answer, but I was unable to create a MWE using Linear.V to solve my problem. The reason, assuming I understand it correctly, I was a little slow to grasp. While the writing of `f` was trivial, I was unable to instantiate a `V n a` object because I didn't know its dimensions at compile time (I was reading data from a file), and so while `f` can be polymorphic on `n`, the instance of `V` itself cannot (as I understand it). ... awkward!

Comment: @sircolinton actually, you can, using existential types.  There isn't one built in in *linear*, but you can make a `data AnyV a where AV :: KnownNat n => V n a -> AnyV a`, which you can pattern match on using case statements, etc.; you just need to make sure that whatever you *do* with the `V n a` is something you can do with *any* `n`...so you are fine to use things like `f` and `g` on it in case statements.

Comment: @JustinL. Ah :-) I didn't realise, thanks! I've not had a chance to try this out yet, but wouldn't `f` (and `g`) then need to be defined in terms of `AnyV a` instead of `V n a`, and if so, wouldn't that cause it to loose its ability to ensure that the lengths of both its parameters are equal?

Comment: @sircolinton you can define f and g in the "safe" way, and then apply then to an AnyV using pattern matching and case statements: `case av of AV v -> AV (f v)`.  The way to make the most of this is similar to the philosophy of pure/impure code etc: write as much of your logic as possible in the safe way, where it's composable and ghc-verifiable and typesafe, and then use it on AV's as one-shots using case statements at the barrier of "pure"  and "impure"  code.