# Using the type system to check length of output vs. input list

Tags: haskell, types, proof, dependent-type

Suppose a list L, with length *n*, is interleaved in list J, with length *n + 1*. 
We'd like to know, for each element of J, which of its neighbors from L is the greater.
The following function takes L as its input, and produces a list K, also of length
*n + 1*, such that the *i*th element of K is the desired neighbor of the *i*th element of J.

```
aux [] prev acc = prev:acc
aux (hd:tl) prev acc = aux tl hd ((max hd prev):acc)

expand row = reverse (aux row 0 [])
```

I can prove to myself, informally, that the length of the result of this function (which I
originally wrote in Ocaml) is one greater than the length of the input. But I
hopped over to Haskell (a new language for me) because I got interested in being
able to prove via the type system that this invariant holds. With the help
of [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32570481/7542694), I was
able to get as far as the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies #-}

data Z
data S n

type family (:+:) a b :: *
type instance (:+:) Z n = n
type instance (:+:) (S m) n = S (m :+: n)

-- A List of length 'n' holding values of type 'a'
data List a n where
    Nil  :: List a Z
    Cons :: a -> List a m -> List a (S m)

aux :: List a n -> a -> List a m -> List a (n :+: (S m))
aux Nil prev acc = Cons prev acc
aux (Cons hd tl) prev acc = aux tl hd (Cons (max hd prev) acc)
```

However, the last line produces the following error:

```
* Could not deduce: (m1 :+: S (S m)) ~ S (m1 :+: S m)
  from the context: n ~ S m1
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               Cons :: forall a m. a -> List a m -> List a (S m),
             in an equation for `aux'
    at pyramid.hs:23:6-15
  Expected type: List a (n :+: S m)
    Actual type: List a (m1 :+: S (S m))
* In the expression: aux tl hd (Cons (max hd prev) acc)
  In an equation for `aux':
      aux (Cons hd tl) prev acc = aux tl hd (Cons (max hd prev) acc)
* Relevant bindings include
    acc :: List a m (bound at pyramid.hs:23:23)
    tl :: List a m1 (bound at pyramid.hs:23:14)
    aux :: List a n -> a -> List a m -> List a (n :+: S m)
      (bound at pyramid.hs:22:1)
```

It seems that what I need to do is teach the compiler that `(x :+: (S y)) ~ S (x :+: y)`. Is this possible?

Alternatively, are there better tools for this problem than the type system?

Comment: It looks possible but it seems to require proving that by induction on `x`, and probably defining and using a singleton for `x` somewhere. Further, this machinery unfortunately won't get erased at runtime, so we will waste O(n) steps only to produce a single `Refl`. (I really wish GHC will optimize this to O(1) someday... :) )

Comment: @chi You've mentioned this sort of GHC optimization several times (that I can recall) and I'm really starting to wish it existed too. Are there any existing efforts for this that you know of?

Comment: @Alec I'm sorry for my prolonged rant/wish, I can't help it :) I'm not following GHC development, so I can't comment on whether there are some plans for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, some imports and language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeInType, RankNTypes, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import Data.Type.Equality
```

We now have [`DataKinds` (or `TypeInType`)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#datatype-promotion) which allows us to promote *any* data to the type level (with its own kind), so the type level naturals really deserve to be defined as a regular `data` (heck, this is *exactly* the motivating examples the previous link to the GHC docs give!). Nothing changes with your `List` type, but `(:+:)` really should be a *closed* type family (now over things of kind `Nat`).

```
-- A natural number type (that can be promoted to the type level)
data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- A List of length 'n' holding values of type 'a'
data List a n where
  Nil  :: List a Z
  Cons :: a -> List a m -> List a (S m)

type family (+) (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Z + n = n
  S m + n = S (m + n)
```

Now, in order to make the proofs work for `aux`, it is useful to define [singleton types](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/tag/singletons/) for natural numbers.

```
-- A singleton type for `Nat`
data SNat n where
  SZero :: SNat Z
  SSucc :: SNat n -> SNat (S n)

-- Utility for taking the predecessor of an `SNat`
sub1 :: SNat (S n) -> SNat n
sub1 (SSucc x) = x

-- Find the size of a list
size :: List a n -> SNat n
size Nil = SZero
size (Cons _ xs) = SSucc (size xs)
```

Now, we are in shape to start proving some stuff. From [`Data.Type.Equality`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html), `a :~: b` represents a proof that `a ~ b`. We need to prove one simple thing about arithmetic.

```
-- Proof that     n + (S m) == S (n + m)
plusSucc :: SNat n -> SNat m -> (n + S m) :~: S (n + m)
plusSucc SZero _ = Refl
plusSucc (SSucc n) m = gcastWith (plusSucc n m) Refl
```

Finally, we can use [`gcastWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#v:gcastWith) to use this proof in `aux`. Oh and you were missing the `Ord a` constraint. :)

```
aux :: Ord a => List a n -> a -> List a m -> List a (n + S m)
aux Nil prev acc = Cons prev acc
aux (Cons hd tl) prev acc = gcastWith (plusSucc (size tl) (SSucc (size acc)))
                                      aux tl hd (Cons (max hd prev) acc)

-- append to a list
(|>) :: List a n -> a -> List a (S n)
Nil |> y = Cons y Nil
(Cons x xs) |> y = Cons x (xs |> y)

-- reverse 'List'
rev :: List a n -> List a n
rev Nil = Nil
rev (Cons x xs) = rev xs |> x
```

---

Let me know if this answers your question - getting started with this sort of thing involves a lot of new stuff.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely what I was looking for — though, as you noted, I'll have to do some reading before I fully understand what's going on here.

Comment: @Levi Roth, you don't need any proofs to define this function: see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2tmxsv/a_type_safe_reverse_or_some_hasochism/) post.

Comment: @user3237465 Are you suggesting we just bypass the proofs manually using unsafeCoerce (because we already know are non-bottom)?

Comment: @user3237465 Ah yes! That is a clever trick I have yet to master. Would this work for the `aux` function OP was asking about? (Note that `rev` doesn't need any proofs here either - but it is much less efficient that the version you linked).

Comment: Yes, it works for `aux` too. Looks something like [this](http://ideone.com/1FoqwG).

Comment: @user3237465 What is the intuition behind making these auxiliary newtypes? I sort of see how they work but I wouldn't be able to come up with one...

Comment: @Alec, it's a way to get type-level lambda to handle polymorphic recursion. E.g. in the definition of `foldlVec` in the recursive case `p` becomes `\n -> p (S n)`, but we don't have type-level lambdas and hence write `Compose p S`. In `aux` I just expressed `\n -> (a, List a (n + S m))` via the `Aux` wrapper which can be partially applied just like `Compose`, so we can instantiate `p` with it. It's a purely mechanical process.