# Transform list in type fixed length in haskell

Tags: haskell

With the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570183/haskell-specifying-equal-length-constraints-of-lists-in-the-type-system) I was able to define a list in witch the length is part of the type:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data ListF (n :: Nat) a where
    Nil :: (ListF 'Z a)
    Cons :: a -> ListF m a -> ListF ('S m) a
```

I would like be able to convert a normal list in to these kind of list. If a make these:

```hs
toListF :: [a] -> ListF n a
toListF [] = Nil
toListF (x:xs) = Cons x (toListF xs)
```

It does't type-check, because for `[a] -> ListF n a` to type-check, the function should return any `Nat` that the caller needs:

```
ListF.hs:11:14: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘n’ with ‘'Z’
      ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          toListF :: forall a (n :: Nat). [a] -> ListF n a
        at ListF.hs:10:1-27
      Expected type: ListF n a
        Actual type: ListF 'Z a
    • In the expression: Nil
      In an equation for ‘toListF’: toListF [] = Nil
    • Relevant bindings include
        toListF :: [a] -> ListF n a (bound at ListF.hs:11:1)
   |
11 | toListF [] = Nil
   |              ^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

The *logical* type for `toListF` I think it wold be something like `exists n. [a] -> ListF n a` or `[a] -> (exists n. ListF n a)`, but of course those are not valid haskell types.

It is possible to do what I am trying to do in haskell? And how?

Comment: There are existential types in Haskell https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type Quite simply `data SomeListF a = forall n . AList (ListF n a)`.

Comment: This is very good! It seems to work for converting from a normal list, thank you
The problem that I have now is that with `SomeListF` I don't now how to express that a function takes and returns a list of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [existential types in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures, RankNTypes #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data ListF (n :: Nat) a where
    Nil :: (ListF 'Z a)
    Cons :: a -> ListF m a -> ListF ('S m) a

data SomeListF a = forall n . AList (ListF n a)
```

You cam convert from a regular list to `SomeListF`:

```
fromList :: [a] -> SomeListF a
fromList [] = AList Nil
fromList (x:xs) = someCons x (fromList xs) where
   someCons x (AList zs) = AList (Cons x zs)
```

You can also recover `ListF`  from `SomeListF`, but only in a restricted scope. The `n` in `forall n` cannot escape, so you cannot have something like

```
toListF :: SomeListF a -> ListF n a
```

but you can have this:

```
withSomeList :: (forall n . ListF n a -> b) -> SomeListF a -> b
withSomeList f (AList zs) = f zs
```

Inside the `f` argument, `n` is known and you can for example map your list and the length of the result is statically known to be the same as the length of the argument. Here's a silly example:

```
zipF :: ListF n a -> ListF n b -> ListF n (a, b)
zipF Nil Nil = Nil
zipF (Cons y ys) (Cons z zs) = Cons (y, z) (zipF ys zs)

mapF :: (a->b) -> ListF n a -> ListF n b
mapF _ Nil = Nil
mapF f (Cons z zs) = Cons (f z) (mapF f zs)

zipMapF :: (a->b) -> ListF n a -> ListF n (a, b)
zipMapF f zs = zipF zs (mapF f zs)

zipMapAny :: (a->b) -> ListF n a -> SomeListF (a, b)
zipMapAny f zs = AList (zipMapF f zs)

nums = fromList [1,2,3,4,5]
numsAndSquares = withSomeList (zipMapAny (\x -> x * x)) nums
```

`zipMapAny` "knows" that the length of all the lists inside it is the same, but it cannot leak that length to the result. You cannot have for example `withSomeList (zipMapF (\x -> x * x)) nums` because `n` would escape.